# Why does form.validate_on_submit() return false on the first form submission?

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-login

I am creating a login form using wtforms, but the login form doesn't work the first time it is submitted. When you submit it for the second time, form.validate_on_submit() *does* return true.

Here is my login view:

```py
@app.route("/login", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('admin'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(user)
            redirect(url_for('admin'))
    return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

And here is my form html:

```html
<form method="POST">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <div class="field">
        <div class="control">
            {{ form.password(class="input is-large", placeholder="Your Password") }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ form.submit(class="button is-block is-success is-large is-fullwidth") }}
</form>
```

Comment: Your form seems to be missing `action` attribute. Are you sure the sample is the same as in your project?

Comment: Yes, I have multiple forms without an action as well and they all work on the first submission.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the bug, in my code I accidentally typed `redirect(url_for('admin'))` instead of `return redirect(url_for('admin'))`.